# Spark write result of Array[Array[Any]] to file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop2

I have input like following sample

```
3070811,1963,1096,,"US","CA",,1,
3022811,1963,1096,,"US","CA",,1,56
3033811,1963,1096,,"US","CA",,1,23
```

After writing replacing the empty chars with 0, i am trying to write the result to textFile and i am getting

```
scala> result.saveAsTextFile("data/result")
<console>:34: error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of Array[Array[Any]]
              result.saveAxtFile("data/result")
```

Here is the solution

```
scala> val file2 = sc.textFile("data/file.txt")
scala> val mapper = file2.map(x => x.split(",",-1))
scala> val result = mapper.map(x => x.map(x => if(x.isEmpty) 0 else x)).collect()
result: Array[Array[Any]] = Array(Array(3070811, 1963, 1096, 0, "US", "CA", 0, 1, 0), Array(3022811, 1963, 1096, 0, "US", "CA", 0, 1, 56), Array(3033811, 1963, 1096, 0, "US", "CA", 0, 1, 23))
scala> result.saveAsTextFile("data/result")
<console>:34: error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of Array[Array[Any]]
              result.saveAsTextFile("data/result")
```

I have also tried following and it failed as well

```
scala> val output = result.map(x => (x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3), x(4), x(5), x(7), x(8)))
output: Array[(Any, Any, Any, Any, Any, Any, Any, Any)] = Array((3070811,1963,1096,0,"US","CA",1,0), (3022811,1963,1096,0,"US","CA",1,56), (3033811,1963,1096,0,"US","CA",1,23))

scala> output.saveAsTextFile("data/output")
<console>:36: error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of Array[(Any, Any, Any, Any, Any, Any, Any, Any)]
              output.saveAsTextFile("data/output")
```

and then added following and it failed as well

```
scala> output.mapValues(_.toList).saveAsTextFile("data/output")
<console>:36: error: value mapValues is not a member of Array[(Any, Any, Any, Any, Any, Any, Any, Any)]
              output.mapValues(_.toList).saveAsTextFile("data/output")
```

How can i view in console or in a result file the contents of result or output variables. Missing something basic here.

**Update 1**

per Shankar Koirala i have removed .collect and then performed save.

```
scala> val result = mapper.map(x => x.map(x => if(x.isEmpty) 0 else x))
```

and this is resulting in this output

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@7a1167b6
[Ljava.lang.Object;@60d86d2f
[Ljava.lang.Object;@20e85a55
```

**Update 1.a**

Picked up the updated answer and it is giving the correct data

```
scala> val result = mapper.map(x => x.map(x => if(x.isEmpty) 0 else x).mkString(","))
result: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[29] at map at <console>:31

scala> result.saveAsTextFile("data/mkstring")
```

result

```
3070811,1963,1096,0,"US","CA",0,1,0
3022811,1963,1096,0,"US","CA",0,1,56
3033811,1963,1096,0,"US","CA",0,1,23
```

**Update 2**

```
scala> val output = result.map(x => (x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3), x(4), x(5), x(7), x(8)))
output: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Any, Any, Any, Any, Any, Any, Any, Any)] = MapPartitionsRDD[27] at map at <console>:33

scala> output.saveAsTextFile("data/newOutPut")
```

and i got this result

```
(3070811,1963,1096,0,"US","CA",1,0)
(3022811,1963,1096,0,"US","CA",1,56)
(3033811,1963,1096,0,"US","CA",1,23)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code returns `Array[Array[Any]]`

```
val result = mapper.map(x => x.map(x => if(x.isEmpty) 0 else x)).collect()
```

Since there is no method `saveAsTextFile` in `Array`

It is available in RDD so you don't need to collect the output

```
val result = mapper.map(x => x.map(x => if(x.isEmpty) 0 else x))
```

Use mkstring() to convert to string and write in file

```
val result = mapper.map(x => x.map(x => if(x.isEmpty) 0 else x).mkString(","))
```

You should also stop using `collect()` which brings all the data to driver which can cause memory issue if data is large.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you have csv file you can use https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv spark csv to read and write the file, which is more easier and efficient.

Comment: Thanks, added section 1.a to the question. mkString worked like update 2